# Serverless + Firebase: API is not reply message

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, firebase, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am creating an api which will update a Firebase Realtime database, using Nodejs, Serverless, Javascript.

my .js file:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("../xxxxxxx-firebase-adminsdk-xxxxxxx.json");

module.exports.saveState = (event, context, callback) => {

    const body = JSON.parse(event.body);

    var timestamp_create = body.timestamp_create;

    try {
        admin.initializeApp({
            credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
            databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxx.firebaseio.com"
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Firebase initialization error', err.stack);
    }


    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref('item/');
    ref.child(timestamp_create).set({
        state: 'empty'
    }, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Data could not be saved." + error);
        } else {
            console.log("Data saved successfully.");
            return callback(null, {
                headers: {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                },
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify({ msg: "Data saved successfully." })
            });

        }
    });

};
```

I deploy API to AWS and test on Postman:

Problem and my attempts:

- After saving item to Firebase Realtime Database, the api didn't reply the message. Api fell into timeout.
- I checked CloudWatch, the log is printed `("Data saved successfully.")`, but it didn't execute the `return callback` at all.
- I tried api in "serverless offline", it works normally, and returns the message.

The API doesn't return callback in AWS environment(lambda).

Any Suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long google and test, I came to a solution for this, leave it here for reference:

The firebase database connection is not released after saving data, so that AWS Lambda cannot return the callback. The simple solution is close database connection after task

```
var ref = db.ref('item/');
    ref.child(timestamp_create).set({
        state: 'empty'
    }, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Data could not be saved." + error);
        } else {
            console.log("Data saved successfully.");

            db.gpOffline(); // this line will release database connection

            return callback(null, {
                headers: {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                },
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify({ msg: "Data saved successfully." })
            });

        }
    });
```